# Why I can't read from file using "file_ptr>>variable" in my program?

Tags: c++, file, c++11, fstream, flush

In the following program I am trying to understand how to read and write  files.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream myfile;
    string str1;
    myfile.open("H:/input_file.txt");
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {   
    myfile<<"test1 writing files"<<" ";
    myfile>>str1;
    cout<<str1<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why I don't get any output on the console even though "test1 writing files" is written into a file?

Comment: Try *flushing* the output.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg what does it mean,and how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file will need to be opened for both read and write (I'm sorry, ignore that; fstream is opened for both read & write by default).  After writing (and flushing the output), you will need to `seekg()` back to the beginning of the file, or you will just be trying to read what comes after the last thing you wrote, which will of course be nothing.

```
myfile<<"test1 writing files"<<" ";
myfile.flush(); 
myfile.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
myfile>>str1;
```

`seekg` is used to change the position you read (get) from the file.  `seekp` is used to change the position you write (put) to the file.

Comment: `std::fstream` by default opens for both input and output. Also, combined input and output streams have separate positions for reading and writing.